# Increasing uGridsToLoad in Fallout: New Vegas

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

What settings can I drop to load more grids without crashing? I can run 9 grids stable but 11 causes the game to crash to desktop. Exterior cell Buffer is at 48 (96=CTD). I want to be able to snipe as far across the map as possible. Perhaps loading low rez buildings and tweaking the LoD? Post me some .ini tweaks please, there is a lot of those LoD and other settings I don't really understand. What settings to drop all the far fake stuff and only load from the real grids?

Answer (score 1):

How many uGrids you can load depends on amount of VRAM you have (and RAM possibly), so maybe you hit a wall with 11. To answer your question what settings to tweak, I would say anything that is VRAM extensive, so textures come to my mind first.